# What is the difference between /dev/input/eventX and /dev/input/jsX?

Tags: linux, input, joystick, gamepad, evdev

When I connect a gamepad on my Linux kernel v5.14 there are two new devices that show up:

```
/dev/input/event23
/dev/input/js1
```

If I `cat <file> | xxd` both device files provide gamepad event information. But `event23` is much more verbose than `js1`.

Also, `evtest` gives error `Invalid Argument` on `js1` but works fine on `event23`. The same happens when I use libevdev both device files.

It looks like with every event, `js1` dumps the contents of an `input_event` struct (defined in `linux/input.h`)

What is the difference between the device files? Why do they have different information and what more information does `event23` provide over `js1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/dev/input/js*` devices are created by the `joydev` legacy joystick driver. It only supports joysticks and joystick-like devices.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/joydev/joystick.html

`/dev/input/event*` devices are created by the `evdev` input event interface. It supports all types of input devices, not just joysticks.

https://linux.die.net/man/4/evdev

The `joydev` interface exposes a subset of the information exposed through `evdev`, specifically it will only expose an input if it looks like a joystick button or axis. New applications should prefer to use `evdev`, but `joydev` is usually still available.

The "looks like a joystick button or axis" heuristic can sometimes be a problem for `joydev`. When a HID gamepad is connected, `evdev` and `joydev` use information in the device's HID report descriptor to detect the number of button and axis inputs. `joydev` only considers buttons from the HID Button usage page, but newer gamepads sometimes define special buttons with different usages. This is especially common for Android gamepads, which have non-Button usages for the Home and Back buttons. These buttons don't get picked up by `joydev`.

Another big difference: `joydev` is purely for input. `evdev` supports gamepad rumble and force feedback effects.